# priority for $\div$ or $\times$ question?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Suppose we need to find the value of :$$(4-4\div 2\times 3-3)\times(4+3-(2\div2\times3))=?$$
question: $\div$ or $\times$ ? which one has higher priority ?

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: They have the same priority, as shown by a 1-second Google search:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi Not when comparing both of them: $(4\div 2)\times 3=6$ while $4\div (2\times 3)=\frac{2}{3}$, as shown by a 5-second careful look at the question.

Comment: You did not understand what I have written. "They have the same priority" means that you must execute them *in the order in which appear*, so the correct operation is $(4 : 2) \times 3$.

Comment: I doubt that's a common practice. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Exceptions

Comment: The better thing is to put parentheses, of course.

Comment: Yep that's right.

Answer (score 3):

Without brackets, $a\div b\times c$ is ambiguous (unlike $a-b+c$, for some reason). Use parentheses or fractions to avoid ambiguity, and you're good to go. As it stands, the expression is ill-defined.

Comment: Although I agree that it is way better to use parentheses, I think that the expression "division and multiplication have the same priority" usually means that you should execute them in the order in which they appear. This is not really different from $a-b+c$.

Comment: You have expressions like $\pi=C\div 2r$, the defining property of $\pi$. Suddenly multiplication has priority just because you don't write the symbol explicitly? It's ambiguous, I say, and I stand by it.

Comment: @S.vanNigtevecht Sorry I missed that.

Comment: Yes, because in this expression you see $2r$ as a "unique entity" (I cannot explain it better). Anyway, it is an ugly notation, it is much better to write $\frac{C}{2r}$.

Comment: In other words, $2r$ is the same as $(2 \times r)$.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi Perhaps. But say you're using $C\div 2r$. Then you get a concrete circle and try to measure $\pi$ from it. You insert a number, say $3$, for $r$, and you have a whole notational mess trying to remember all the special rules and what things really mean. I just find it's too much to keep track of, especially if we are to teach this to young kids.

Answer (score 1):

In lower grade, we were taught BDMAS.

Bracket, Division, Multiplication, Addition, Subtraction as the order for computation.
Although, $$a\div b=a \times\frac{1}{b}\text{ if } (b \ne 0)$$

So it's advisable to use brackets to clear confusion

Answer (score 0):

They have the same priority: $a\div b=a\times\dfrac{1}{b}$ if $b\neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, students in the US are taught order of operations with the mnemonic PEMDAS: Parentheses, Exponents, Multiplication, Division, Addition, Subtraction with the caveat that Multiplication and Division have equal priority and Addition and Subtraction have equal priority. When you have two operations of equal priority, you execute them from left to right.

In your example, the division would be executed before the multiplication because it comes first (it's on the left). If this is a problem in a text book and the intent of the problem is to have you practice order of operations, then the answer should be $-20$. However, if the context of this is anything other than for practicing order of operations, the expression is extremely ambiguous and the author should use more parentheses (and brackets, if necessary) to clarify the intent.